# Is it possible to use Lottie for emails?

Tags: email, animation, gif, animated-gif, lottie

I am not a programmer, I am a graphic designer. I have designed a banner for an email animated in after effects. I would like to find a solution for not heavy animation on email. I have researched that Lottie could be good for file size the problem is that I am not sure if you can integrate that in campaign monitor or MailChimp and how. Another option is upload it on Vimeo and then link it as a div in html.

Does anyone have experience in this? Or know a different way to make an animation super light for email?

Apologises I am beginner in html/CSS. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Lottie depends on Javascript this is currently not possible. You can however convert the animations from LottieFiles to GIFs or MP4s and use those instead.

Comment: Hi Sam,

Thanks for your reply. How would you insert in an email an MP4, I guess by embed it right as a div in css/html, right?

Many thanks!

Comment: Since you talked about using mailchimp:

https://mailchimp.com/en-gb/help/add-video-to-a-campaign/